# how to check if I have done a git commit --amend over some commit?

Tags: git

I am on a branch that has 3 commits till date. I just wanted to check if the head commit is due to simple `git commit` or `git commit --amend`.
Actually I raised a code review from this branch and now, I can't see that commit message I used for raising code review. by mistake, I might have `amend` that commit.
How can I see the history of commits which include all commit which is due to `git commit` and `git commit --amend`?
anyone can tell me the right approach?

Comment: Run `git reflog` and its output may give you clues.